# What is stored in the GPG trustdb file?

Tags: gpg

the [GPG documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html#gpg_002doption-_002d_002doptions) explains that the file name of the trustdb can be changed:

```
--trustdb-name file
```

But for what it is used? What is stored in the file?

Comment: I think it has to do with [this](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html).

Answer (score 1):

The file stores [the trust database](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html). The trust database is used, in association with the web of trust, to calculate how much weight to give to the identity information attaches to each key.

If you’ve signed Alice’s key, presumably you trust yourself to verify her identity in a way that meets your expectations. By defining how much trust you put in Alice’s verifications, you allow GnuPG to determine how much trust to put in keys that Alice has signed but not you. Trust is also calculated transitively, see the GnuPG manual for details.

Comment: When I sign a key, the signature goes into the trustdb?

Comment: No, key signatures are added to the key itself, and shared.